# QuartzCore shadow - lag UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, core-animation, shadow, lag

I have an UITableView (NOTE:The UITableView is in a UIView) and I thought it would be nice to have an shadow added below it. I add the shadow with QuartzCore and it turns out really nice. But I also notice that when I come back from a 'Detail View' the animation back to the root is a bit lag. I've heard that QuartzCore and CoreAnimation can make the app slower, or in this case, add lag.

First, am I right that CoreAnimation makes the app slower?

If so, how can I keep my shadow but remove the slowness and lag?

Thanks and I appreciate all thoughts and answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting another view the same size behind the table view and have *that* view generate the shadow. Also, layer shadows are much more efficient if you supply an explicit `shadowPath`. The *most* efficient way is to draw the shadow yourself using Core Graphics.

Comment: Thanks, but I have no experience with Core Graphics. I've heard of `shadowpath` before but never used it.

Comment: Well, I've written you a book that explains all about it. :) And the drawing chapter is free to read online.http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html